# Is there any way to get the textfield information of a container?

Tags: swift, swift2, containers

Own two viewcontroller is the second of a container.
When trying to get the textfield the text that is in the container the return I get is nil.

Is there any way to get the textfield information of a container?

[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgBIV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to replace the custom view (container) by fields programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

When one view controller is put into a container in a storyboard, an embed segue is created. Your containing view controller can access the contained one via `prepareForSegue()`, like this:

```
var weak containedTextField: UITextField!

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "<whatever-ID-you-set-on-your-segue>" {
        if let containedViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? <your-embedded-view-controller's-type> {
            containedTextField = containedViewController.textField
        }
    }
}
```

Your containing view controller can then use the `textField` instance however it needs to.

Comment: I used this method as the code below but it did not work.

func override prepareForSegue (follows: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject)
     {
         if segue.identifier == "segueID"
         {
             if let containedViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? firstViewController
             {
             containedViewController.varfirstview = TextField.text
             }
         }
     }

Comment: `segue.destinationViewController as? firstViewController` shouldn't even compile.

Comment: I don't get it. I worked with this example you went though all the ways the return is nil. Even trying to get the text within the own view the return is nil.